# javascript/svg submit form or input button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

Can someone please guide me on how to go about creating a submit form or input button that can be used to create the option of adding for example shapes to the screen.

for example something like do you want 2, 3 or 4 shapes on the screen then you choose and press submit or just click with an input button the amount you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is present in the DOM. You can simply attach your function to create shapes to any element using javascript. Here is a simple example I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/aq6nG/6/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a submit button or even a form..
Just include the Raphael library and create any number of Shapes.
There's lots of examples at..
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/
On iPod so basic answer at this stage but will check back later..